# passing parameter from one page to another page in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, parameters, xhtml, managed-bean

i am little bit stuck in my problem. i have sent the parameter from one `xhtml` page to another `xhtml` page successfully and i printed that `parameter` on my next page `xhtml` like this, `#{param['id']}`, but the problem is my `@postConstructor` is not executing, because i want that whenever my next page loads the `parameter id` sends over to `database` and get the required details in my `datatable`.

here is my code snippet of `xhtml` page from where i am sending `parameters`

```
<h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                        Title
            </f:facet>
                        <h:link value="#{item.title}" outcome="showObj.xhtml">
                        <f:param name="pid" value="#{item.id}" />
                        </h:link>   
            </h:column>
```

and here is my `managedBean`

```
package mb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;


import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean(name="next")
@RequestScoped
public class showObj implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.pid}")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("in getter"+name);
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @PostConstruct // this will execute init() after id is injected
    public void init() {

        System.out.println("in init");
    }



}
```

and here is my next `xhtml` page content, where i am receiving `parameters`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{param['pid']}"></h:outputText>
```

now i want that whenever my this `parameter` is received here, on page loading this `parameter` should send to `database` (the other `ejb` project). i know that if my `@postConstructor` runs than i can achieve this thing. but my `@postConstructor` is not executing.

i have also searched my problem over internet, they all says something about `mojarra` version, so i let you know that i have `2.1.6` version

Comment: no, i just want to say that the `param` which i received in the next page `showObj.xhtml`, is passing correctly, but my `init` method in `managed bean` is not executing so that i can send it to `database` from there

Comment: the all thing which i am doing is in my question

Comment: @BalcusC , i am not getting your point, can you please tell me with an example. as i am new in jsf

Comment: as i am new to jsf, so i didnt know this thing that bean should also be instantiated in order to run managed bean

Comment: so you think that by instantiating my bean will run `@postConstruct`